# failed to run custom build command for `ring v0.16.12`

Tags: rust, blockchain, rust-cargo, apple-m1, solana

I am building this (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana) on my new Mac m1 and it failed.

The author of `ring` says it can be fixed by upgrading dependency (https://github.com/briansmith/ring/issues/1163).

I tried add `ring = "0.16.19"` to `cargo.toml` but failed because `this virtual manifest specifies a [dependencies] section, which is not allowed`

I tried to search `ring` in the project directory and I only find them in `cargo.lock`.

It seems `ring` is a dependency of dependency of Solana. I am new to Rust and I do not know how to fix this.

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `ring v0.16.12`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/pt/code/solana/target/debug/build/ring-15a328b7ae57ee29/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  CARGO: /Users/pt/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/cargo
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ARCH: aarch64
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ENDIAN: little
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ENV: 
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FAMILY: unix
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_OS: macos
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_POINTER_WIDTH: 64
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_VENDOR: apple
  CARGO_CFG_UNIX: 
  CARGO_FEATURE_ALLOC: 1
  CARGO_FEATURE_DEFAULT: 1
  CARGO_FEATURE_DEV_URANDOM_FALLBACK: 1
  CARGO_FEATURE_LAZY_STATIC: 1
  CARGO_HOME: /Users/pt/.cargo
  CARGO_MAKEFLAGS: --jobserver-fds=3,7 -j --jobserver-auth=3,7 -j
  CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR: /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12
  CARGO_MANIFEST_LINKS: ring-asm
  CARGO_PKG_AUTHORS: Brian Smith <brian@briansmith.org>
  CARGO_PKG_DESCRIPTION: Safe, fast, small crypto using Rust.
  CARGO_PKG_HOMEPAGE: 
  CARGO_PKG_LICENSE: 
  CARGO_PKG_LICENSE_FILE: LICENSE
  CARGO_PKG_NAME: ring
  CARGO_PKG_REPOSITORY: https://github.com/briansmith/ring
  CARGO_PKG_VERSION: 0.16.12
  CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MAJOR: 0
  CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MINOR: 16
  CARGO_PKG_VERSION_PATCH: 12
  CARGO_PKG_VERSION_PRE: 
  DEBUG: true
  DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH: /Users/pt/code/solana/target/debug/deps:/Users/pt/code/solana/target/debug:/Users/pt/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib:/Users/pt/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib:/Users/pt/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib
  HOME: /Users/pt
  HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /opt/homebrew/Cellar
  HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew
  HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /opt/homebrew
  HOST: aarch64-apple-darwin
  INFOPATH: /opt/homebrew/share/info:
  LANG: en_US.UTF-8
  LOGNAME: pt
  MANPATH: /opt/homebrew/share/man::
  NUM_JOBS: 8
  OLDPWD: /Users/pt/code
  OPT_LEVEL: 0
  OUT_DIR: /Users/pt/code/solana/target/debug/build/ring-9a6dbe2fa4a00fbb/out
  PATH: /Users/pt/.cargo/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/pt/.cargo/bin
  PROFILE: debug
  PWD: /Users/pt/code/solana
  RUSTC: rustc
  RUSTDOC: rustdoc
  RUSTUP_HOME: /Users/pt/.rustup
  RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN: stable-aarch64-apple-darwin
  RUST_RECURSION_COUNT: 1
  SHELL: /bin/zsh
  SHLVL: 1
  SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.w1r5O8sb2j/Listeners
  TARGET: aarch64-apple-darwin
  TERM: xterm-256color
  TERM_PROGRAM: Apple_Terminal
  TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION: 440
  TERM_SESSION_ID: 8998128C-3738-440D-9638-CBD45E430CAF
  TMPDIR: /var/folders/yy/vchg_vkn3b99gk27n12cs09c0000gn/T/
  USER: pt
  XPC_FLAGS: 0x0
  XPC_SERVICE_NAME: 0
  _: /Users/pt/.cargo/bin/cargo
  __CFBundleIdentifier: com.apple.Terminal
  __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING: 0x1F5:0x0:0x0
  all_proxy: socks5://127.0.0.1:7890
  http_proxy: http://127.0.0.1:7890
  https_proxy: http://127.0.0.1:7890
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  TARGET = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
  HOST = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
  CC_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CC_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CFLAGS_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = None
  running "cc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-gfull" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/Users/pt/code/solana/target/debug/build/ring-9a6dbe2fa4a00fbb/out/aesv8-armx-linux64.o" "/Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S"

  --- stderr
  /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:18:17: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
  .section .rodata
                  ^
  /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:28:1: error: unknown directive
  .hidden GFp_aes_hw_set_encrypt_key
  ^
  /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:29:1: error: unknown directive
  .type GFp_aes_hw_set_encrypt_key,%function
  ^
  /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:161:1: error: unknown directive
  .size GFp_aes_hw_set_encrypt_key,.-GFp_aes_hw_set_encrypt_key
  ^
  /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:163:1: error: unknown directive
  .hidden GFp_aes_hw_encrypt
  ^
  /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:164:1: error: unknown directive
  .type GFp_aes_hw_encrypt,%function
  ^
  /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:191:1: error: unknown directive
  .size GFp_aes_hw_encrypt,.-GFp_aes_hw_encrypt
  ^
  /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:193:1: error: unknown directive
  .hidden GFp_aes_hw_decrypt
  ^
  /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:194:1: error: unknown directive
  .type GFp_aes_hw_decrypt,%function
  ^
  /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:221:1: error: unknown directive
  .size GFp_aes_hw_decrypt,.-GFp_aes_hw_decrypt
  ^
  /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:223:1: error: unknown directive
  .hidden GFp_aes_hw_ctr32_encrypt_blocks
  ^
  /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:224:1: error: unknown directive
  .type GFp_aes_hw_ctr32_encrypt_blocks,%function
  ^
  /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:403:1: error: unknown directive
  .size GFp_aes_hw_ctr32_encrypt_blocks,.-GFp_aes_hw_ctr32_encrypt_blocks
  ^
  /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S:407:19: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
  .section .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
                    ^
  thread 'main' panicked at 'execution failed', /Users/pt/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.12/build.rs:641:9
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Comment: "this toml is a virtual one" - what do you mean here? There's some Cargo.toml file where you've placed dependency on Solana, right?

Comment: @Cerberus Modified to explain your question. There is a Cargo.toml in the root directory of Solana and I tried to modify that .toml.

Comment: Will `cargo update` or deleting Cargo.lock help here? This should pull the newest compatible version.

Comment: @Cerberus No, it still pull the old one. I deleted the whole repo, deleted .lock and `update`.

Comment: having same issue here. tried a few fixes but im not sure whats wrong I think I saw on another post somewhere to change the ring requirement.

Comment: Any solution to this? Facing same issue!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70628855/2420718

Comment: Windows, run this in project dir: rustup override set stable-msvc