# error: failed to run custom build command for `ring v0.16.20`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, alpine-linux, musl

I want to build rust 1.59 project with musl in macOS Monterey 12.3.1 with M1 chip, then I run this command:

```
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
cargo build --release --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

but the project build output like this:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `ring v0.16.20`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/foo/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/release/build/ring-98ce1debbcda4321/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-musl")
  HOST = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
  CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl = None
  CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl = None
  TARGET_CC = None
  CC = None
  CROSS_COMPILE = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl = None
  TARGET_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")

  --- stderr
  running "musl-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/Users/foo/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-a5403edcb6d58bf6/out/aesni-x86_64-elf.o" "/Users/foo/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.20/pregenerated/aesni-x86_64-elf.S"
  thread 'main' panicked at 'failed to execute ["musl-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/Users/foo/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-a5403edcb6d58bf6/out/aesni-x86_64-elf.o" "/Users/foo/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.20/pregenerated/aesni-x86_64-elf.S"]: No such file or directory (os error 2)', /Users/foo/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.20/build.rs:653:9
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

why did this happen? is it possible to fix this problem? what should I do to fixed this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to cross-compile your program (compile for a target which is different from the host), or are you just trying to run it locally?

Comment: I am trying to cross compile, I just read the docs found it will be a little bit complex. I am still learning. I am not femiliar with these lib about musl. @JeremyMeadows

Comment: Any update on this? I have a similar problem. How did you continue?

Comment: Ok, found it. Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because most likely you forgot to install.

> See if you have musl-gcc on the build host.
>
> `$ musl-gcc`
>
> `Command 'musl-gcc' not found, but can be installed with:`
>
> `sudo apt install musl-tools`

Thanks to [mbergkvist](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63939#issuecomment-665952545)

Comment: Building on Debian with `musl-tools` and then deploying on Alpine solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: is there a compatible tool on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you've tagged "alpine-linux", I will assume you're using alpine.

In that case to get musl-gcc to work as mentioned by other commenter you'll need `musl-dev` package

```
apk add --no-cache musl-dev
```

This is how I solved my exact problem in *alpine*.

Anyone who is using the `rust:1-alpine` or similar image and facing the same issue, add the following to your Dockerfile

```
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade

RUN apk add --no-cache musl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run `cargo build` with the commands below:

```
$ alias rust-musl-builder='docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd)":/home/rust/src ekidd/rust-musl-builder'
$ rust-musl-builder cargo build --release
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70628855/132257

Answer (score 0):

On Windows run this in the project dir:

`rustup override set stable-msvc`

Turns out, simply setting default toolchain was not enough as cargo would install the gnu version every time I ran cargo run.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on Windows, to solve this issue you need to be using WSL2.
Run `cargo build` under wsl2 and your build will succeed without problems.