# rust build error:failed to run custom build command for `ring v0.16.20`

Tags: android, rust, ring, hyper

Device: Mac
Cargo.toml:

```toml
hyper={version="0.14.16",features=["full"]}
hyper-rustls = "0.24.1"
```

Build:

```
cargo build --target aarch64-linux-android --release
```

error:

```
failed to run custom build command for `ring v0.16.20`
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully:`/Users/laiyi/rust/android_demo/target/release/build/ring-2d5afaebac3dba3f/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
```

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAdYc.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also please take the time to format your question correctly. It is currently very hard to read, with code and text mixed and missing line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

as the name says, ring seems to have returned a 101 return message, meaning something is either missing or wrong in your setup. I don't have a mac so i don't know what dependencies does rust need, but at least make sure you have rustup properly installed. if you're sure that rustup is installed right, then you should use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68149955/rust-sorry-unimplemented-64-bit-mode-not-compiled-in/70628855#70628855) to solve it